# nginx and DNS subdomain, too many redirects

Tags: apache, nginx, web, subdomain

I just installed nginx and set it to work over an apache installation. As a matter of fact, my rules are:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

   location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Readl-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_pass http://example.com:8080;
   }

   location ~ /\.ht {
       deny all;
   }
}
```

and I wanted to configure a subdomain by:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name sub.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:8080/sub;
    }

    location ~/\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And configuring my DNS like so:

```
NAME     |     TYPE     |     TARGET
//empty         A           45.23.67.89
 sub           CNAME        example.com
```

I waited for propagation, but i'm getting "too many redirects" in chrome...

The response is always 301, and redirected to the IP:80, I'm guessing that this is caused because of the A line in DNS... howver domain.com does redirect to apache and I do get the "it works" we all know so well...

Can anyone one point me to the right direction please?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:

I added another subdowmain, sub-sub, following **EXACTLY** the same procedure, but it magically works... need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Solved,

I added headers to the proxy_pass directive and it worked

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

However, it's still adding me a slash (/) at the end of the url, meaning that when i go to `sub.example.com` i get `sub.exmaple.com//`

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
ProxyRequests off 
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2368/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http:/127.0.0.1:2368/               
</VirtualHost>
```

This config was taken from Apache2 not sure if this will work on Nginx but this fixes it on Apache2. Obviously change the port of the localhost. That config is for Ghost Blog.

This will redirect the visitor to a specific port, this is good if you have HTTPS or SSL enabled and it's getting too many redirect requests. You can set the port to 443 (SSL port).